# How to create this type of relationship using Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

After seeing a model that I should implement in Django, I was a little confused and I will explain what I tried to do and what was sent to me.
The following image is the relationship I must implement in Django

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOYNq.png

What I tried to do was:

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
     person = models.OneToOneField(Person)

class Person(models.Model):
     contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

However this does not work, both classes are in the same file. I read the documentation for ManyToManyField, OneToOneField and ForeignKey, but what makes me confused is the model wanting the variable in both classes, in previous models that I saw there was this same relationship, but the variable only existed in one of the classes. What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: You have a circular dependency here. Unfortunately, I can not open the image due to restrictions at work. But if you need circular dependencies in models, you can specify the model in the relationship field with: `models.OneToOneField('Person')` or `models.ForeignKeyField('Contact')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the solution is just using:

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=False)
```

It sole the problem.